# Updating the name of SpecFlow scenario outline variations

Tags: naming, specflow, gherkin, scenarios

I have this feature file:

```
Scenario Outline: Example
    Given I am a user
    When I enter <x> as an amount
    Then the result should be <result>
    Examples:
        | x | result |
        | 3 | 3      |
        | 1 | 1      |
```

My issue is that after it's run, each example is labeled as `variant #`

Is there a way to name what each example line is actually testing, so that in the report, we know better what is tested, not just:

```
Scenario: Example, Variant 0
Scenario: Example, Variant 1
Scenario: Example, Variant 2
```

I'm trying to help our testers get more meaningful reports; there is typically a reason they write multiple examples, and they want that reason for that example shown somehow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the SpecFlow [Scenario Outlines](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Using-Gherkin-Language-in-SpecFlow#wiki-scenario-outlines) documentation says:

> the Gherkin syntax does not enforce that all example columns have
>   the matching placeholder in the scenario outline, you can even
>   introduce an arbitrary column in the example sets for better test
>   method name readability

So you could introduce an arbitrary column into your "Examples" table to succinctly describe the intention of the test e.g.

```
Scenario Outline: Example
    Given I am a user
    When I enter <x> as an amount
    Then the result should be <result>
    Examples:
        | example description   | x | result |
        | Example Description 1 | 3 | 3      |
        | Example Description 2 | 1 | 1      |
```

This would result in the following test names:

```
Example_ExampleDescription1
Example_ExampleDescription2
```

Comment: @CaffGeek Cool. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: If anyone has having trouble with SpecFlow still using the "variant" naming schema even after adding a label column make sure that all the values therein are unique!  A single dupe will cause it to revert back.

Comment: @DavidPeters thank you so much for this. Was doing my head in.

Comment: I dont understand how this works. My test name always describe the full example table row e.g. test name is:
NP10_New_Record_Details_Tab_Info("Prod010a","Product","01/10/2020","10.00",null)

How do you get it to only use one Example table column in the test name?

Comment: @m_finn do you have solution to have short name?

Comment: @cashmere - I asked the question here but dont think i got a solution (reply from Specflow)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64331788/specflow-scenario-outline-change-auto-generated-test-name

Sorry i cant check as no longer work there.