# Why my test scenario name not consist of both the title of the scenario outline and the value in the first additional column

Tags: specflow

According to 
[Updating the name of SpecFlow scenario outline variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21946550/updating-the-name-of-specflow-scenario-outline-variations) If I write an additional column as the first column, then the SpecFlow code generator will use the value from that column to name the test method

I have written a Specflow scenario outline like this:

[image]

but why the name of test scenarios still are "Example" not like "Example_odd-number".

My specflow version is 2.2.0, Nunit version is 3.7.1.

[image]

Comment: From the Specflow wiki: "If the unit test framework supports it" and "Hint: In certain cases, ...SpecFlow is unable to generate the correct parameter signatures for unit test logic methods without a little help."  Start there.

Comment: Could you post parts of the code-behind file of this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the way how 2.2 works now.

Set the following and re-generate the feature files:

```
<specFlow>
  <generator 
      allowRowTests="false" />
</specFlow>
```