# How to achieve more unique or readable test names when using excel as a test data source in Specflow ExternalData

Tags: c#, specflow

The test names that get generated while using excel as a test data source in Specflow ExternalData are not at all user friendly.

I was trying something similar to "example testId_identifier" as the first column and populate it with unique data but I still get the test name as below:

```
OMS_CRD_Workflow_SecTypes_ValueExists("COMBB_GLOBAL_ID","COM","BB_xxxx_ID","BBGXXXXXX","True","True","","","True","","","","","","","False","","","","","","True","","","","","True","True","","True","","","","True","")
```

Basically this is creating the test name with all the column values rather than just use the value under column header "example testId_identifier". This works fine if we are not using excel as an input sheet but if we provide all data under examples inside the .specflow file

Is there a way one can fix this?

Below is an example (I realised it is just not for xlsx input but for all inputs):

```
Scenario Outline: Example
    Given I am a user
    When I enter <x> as an amount
    Then the result should be <result>
    Examples:
        | example description   | x | result |
        | Example Description 1 | 3 | 3      |
        | Example Description 2 | 1 | 1      |
```

This should result in the following test names:

```
Example_ExampleDescription1
Example_ExampleDescription2
```

The issue though is we see the unreadable formate being displayed:

```
Example("Example Description 1","3","3",null)
Example("Example Description 2","1","1",null)
```

This used to be working in the previous versions of specflow not sure why it isnt working now. This is quite important in multiple places I have worked and would be really good if can be fixed.
I am using Nunit runner for this.

Comment: We do not have enough information to provide you an answer. Please [edit] your question to include a [repro].

Comment: @GregBurghardt I have updated the description with an example.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I see a simlar question asked here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64331788/specflow-scenario-outline-change-auto-generated-test-name  is this still the case? I tried xunit and it still doesnt come up with a readable test name.